# Cyrillic in Lyx

Tags: lyx, cyrillic

Is it possible in Lyx to type the entire text in Cyrillic and when mathematical formulas come, to remain in standard Latin, without having to constantly change the keyboard language (shift+alt).

For example, I set the keyboard language to Cyrillic and type text, after that, I change the keyboard to English just to type only a>b and then again to change the keyboard to Cyrillic to type the rest of the text. It is a little bit frustrating to change the keyboards all the time.

Example:

Пример текса $a>b$ пример текста.

Comment: Good question, I can see how that would be useful. I don't think LyX currently ever changes your system keyboard, and I'm not sure it would consider doing so (I can imagine some users would be upset with one application changing a system-wide property), although I could be wrong. One approach might be for you to use a system-level shortcut-manager. This way, when you execute the shortcut to start math (e.g., ctrl + m), first the shortcut-manager executes a system command to change the keyboard language, then it passes ctrl + m down to LyX.